# Multiple row insert into MS Sql Server using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, database

I am trying to insert multiple rows into MS SQL server using C#. My code inserts one value into the DB but then throws an exception. 
I am new to C# and would appreciate any help.

Code I am using :

```
 private int InsertDataintoDB()
    {
        var dbConnection = new DBConnection();
        UserAppList userAppList = new UserAppList();
        userAppList.initList();
        var sqlString = "Insert into dbo.[OneSiteUserAccess](UserType, ApplicationCode) values(@appuserType,@appCode)";
        string connectionString = dbConnection.GetLASCentralWriterConnectionString();
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        int rowsAffected = 0;
        List<USerType_AndAppCode> mylist = userAppList.myList;
        try
        {

            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
            sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlCommand.CommandText = sqlString;
            sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
            mytextArea.Append(sqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout.ToString());

            foreach (var user in mylist)
            {

                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@appuserType", user.UserType);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@appCode", user.AppCode);
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                rowsAffected++;

            }
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }

        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            mytextArea.Append(e.StackTrace);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace); mytextArea.Append(e.StackTrace);
        }

        return rowsAffected;
    }
}
```

Error I am getting

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
>   ds)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
>   WebApplication_EmptyWebApp1.UserData.InsertDataintoDB() in
>   c:\Users\csaini\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\WebApplication_EmptyWebApp1\WebApplication_EmptyWebApp1\UserData.aspx.cs:line
>   120rows inserted : 1
>
> > Blockquote

Comment: Why do you use OpenAsync ? Plain old Open wil do.

Answer (score 4):

i think the issue may be the `AddWithValue` inside the `foreach` loop.
for each iteration you add the same parameter over and over.
your code should be something like this (check the syntax):

```
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
sqlCommand.CommandText = sqlString;
sqlConnection.Open();
mytextArea.Append(sqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout.ToString());

sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@appuserType", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@appCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

foreach (var user in mylist)
{

    sqlCommand.Parameters["@appuserType"].Value = user.UserType;
    sqlCommand.Parameters["@appCode"].Value = user.AppCode;
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    rowsAffected++;

}
sqlConnection.Close();
```